# System.Net Error: 0 : [8764] Exception in the SmtpClient#39532060::Send - Unable to read data from the transport connection : net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I know that this question looks like duplicate of other questions while it's not.

Whenever I try to send an email on production through my web application an SMTPException is thrown (not all the time, once per four times) and the exception is :

```
System.Net Error: 0 : [8764] Exception in the SmtpClient#39532060::Send - Unable to read data from the transport connection : net_io_connectionclosed.
```

While the code on local is working perfectly, the same code, the same connections, the same credentials.

The config in both local and production :

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="@email">
   <network host="mailtrap.io" password="@pwd" port="25" userName="@usr"/>
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Can anyone give just a hint what could be the problem that raising this issue?

Comment: Reducing timeout to 10 sec worked for me and solved problem